# Java swap method using pointers only

Tags: java

```
public void swap(int index)
{
    //If the index = 0, then swap 0 and 1, if 10 is given, swap 10 and 11.
    Node current = start;

    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        current = current.next;
    }

    // = 2
    Node temp = current;
    // = 3
    Node temp2 = current.next;

    System.out.println("Temp = " + temp.value + " | Refernces to: " + temp);
    System.out.println("Temp = " + temp2.value + " | Refernces to: " + temp2);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Current is 3 and now we switching to 2 | Current: " + current.value);
    System.out.println();
    //2 then goes to 3
    current = temp2;
    System.out.println("Current must equal 3 | Current: " + current.value);
    System.out.println();
    //3 turns into 2
    System.out.println("Current must equal 2 | Current: " + current.value);
    System.out.println();

    current = temp;

    System.out.println("Now current is suppose to be 3: " + current.value);


    System.out.println();

    current = start;
    while(current != null)
    {
        System.out.println(current.value + " | " + current);
        current = current.next;
    }

}
```

This uses a list of 1,2,3,4 trying to swap the index value and the next value. Problem is I can't just do the smart "switch values" thing. I must switch the pointers, but as you might see it refuses to switch properly

I have yet to find any person dealing with the combo of swapping 2 values next to each other and being unable to use values

UPDATE: Some fixes. It perfectly switches nodes according to prints. Problem is I still can't get this to save making a print out print 1,3,2,4

Comment: `current = current.next;` is overwritten by `current = temp;`.

Comment: Commented that out. Did not change results

Comment: What results? You haven't explained what you're trying to do or what's not working.

Comment: "trying to swap the index value and the next value" Result being the list printed at the end doesn't change

Comment: 57 lines to swap two nodes in a list?

Comment: A lot are comments + prints

Comment: this seems wrong `current = current.next; current = temp;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume "index value" is current and "next value" is current.next,

The principle is to use the parent of current.

And for the first element you need the special variable that holds the first element of the list - i called it start.
To clarify the later you have:

list -> item0-> item1 -> item2 -> ...

This first variable "list" here is the "head" or "anchor". The variable you stored the first element is the head(or "anchor") called it start(like in the OP).

```
public void swap(int index) {
    Node prev;
    Node next;
    Node current = start;
    //special treatment, as the head changes!
    if (0 == index) {
        //define
        next = current.next;
        //do the swap
        current.next = next.next;
        next.next = current;
        start = next;   // the head changes!
        return;
    }
    //stop one before the one you need to swap(index-1)
    for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++) {
        current = current.next;
        System.out.println("Value is: " + current.value);
    }
    //define
    prev = current;
    current = prev.next;
    next = current.next;
    // do the swap:
    prev.next = next;
    current.next = next.next;
    next.next = current;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works. Still trying to understand nodes better